# Ember components with itemController

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have 1 timeline on route `posts` with 2 types of post: from facebook and from twitter, both with same controller: `post` with 2 methods: `isFacebook` and `isTwitter`.

There's a component for each type of post and an 'post-index' with use this 2 methods to redener the correct component.

Route `post` with default `ArrayController`:

```
 <ul class="timeline">
  {{#each post in model itemController="posts.post"}}
    <li> {{post-index post=post}} </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

post-index

```
{{#if post.isFacebook}}
   {{post-facebook post=post}}
{{/if}}

{{#if post.isTwitter}}
    {{post-twitter post=post}}
{{/if}}

{{yield}}
```

The problem is when I try render a single post in route `post.post` with post-index template
route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        controller.set('model', model);
  }
});
```

template:

```
 <ul class="timeline">
     {{#each post in model}}
         <li> {{post-index post=post}} </li>
      {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

My route `posts` only works because it have `itemController="posts.post"`
but `post.post` don't. What I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wondering how to pass the post itself to the post to the `post` property of `post-index`.

If so, you can modify your code as follows:

```
 <ul class="timeline">
     {{#each post in model}}
         <li> {{post-index post=this}} </li>
      {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

The only change is to change post to `this`. Since you are in an `each` block `this` will pass the item for the current iteration.

Comment: Correct, but to decide what component render(twitter or facebook) `post-index` needs use the controller(`posts.post`) methods(isFacebook/isTwitter this will check a model property), or this logic should be moved( where?) ?

Comment: I am not sure I 100% understand your question. Does your model have the `isFacebook` and `isTwitter` methods? If so, passing the post into `post-index` and leveraging the logic you've posted within the template should work. Is anything not functioning as you expect?

Comment: my model have `social_network` attr. 
My controller `posts.post` methods `#isFacebook` `#isTwitter` return true  if this property is 'facebook' or 'twitter', but this create dependency between the controller and the component. I need a way in `post-index` to decide with component render.

Comment: Resolved: In my `post-index` template I should use {{#if this.isFacebook}} and add this method in component "controller".
thanks for helping. My error is insist in itemController.